# Ternary Relationship- SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I want to implement in my SQL code a ternary relation between 3 tables (tab1,tab2,tab3). (1:1:N)

For that I need to create a new (connecting) table right? (s. picture)

My question is: what is the relation between the new `connecting_table` and the other tables?

- Is it one-to-one, one-to-one and one-to-many

OR

- one-to-many, one-to-many and many-to-many

?

for example:
There's an app for a university-canteen. You can log in and preorder food and inform yourself about the dishes. 
Tab1= User, tab2= product, tab3=payment.
the relation between the three is "buys". 
The new connecting_tab=Order.

Comment: The last time I saw such diagrams was at university where we were learning useless ideas. Can you provide the concrete scenario? It's much easier to intuitively find a solution then.

Comment: Generally, 1:1 relationships can be folded into one table. So the top right diagram can be simplified to two tables.

Comment: i'm in university :D i got this ER-Modell from my prof. -edited it (hope it's understandable)

Comment: so are the new relations automatically one-to-one, one-to-one and one-to-many? that in the ER-Modell (in my question) the upper solution would be the case? or does you have "logically" decide if there's an N(many) or 1 in the relation on the side of the new table ?

Comment: What about new tables `Orders(UserID, PaymentAmountOrWhatever), OrderItems(OrderID, ProductID, Quantity)`? That's the (usual) shop data model. So the payment gets folded into the order (assuming there are exactly 0 or 1 payments). Note, that it's not OK to stuff everyting into OrderItems because that duplicates the payment info.

Comment: it's a task and he said we should stick with the given entitys, even if we see something we would like to improve :/ also this is just a small part of a bigger ER-Modell.

Comment: That's bad news :) I guess his "buys" kind of is what my OrderItems is. But it does not map exactly. I don't know how to solve the problem given these constraints. Good luck. Is there just one product per order?

Comment: no i think you can buy different products at once. i guess i go with the first solution in my code, sound more logical that 1 order can also have just 1 payment and just 1 user, but serveral products. hope it's right that way. but really thank you for your help!

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing about the "correct" solution once it's revealed to you.

Comment: i will post it. probably around thursday or friday